# Restructure JavaScript Array of Objects by another predefined Array element as key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I put the same code also on jsbin: https://jsbin.com/literefeqo/edit?js,console

**Explanation**

I’ve got an array of objects (1) and would like to transform (possibly using map) this object. The transformation criteria is a given array (2) and corresponds to the `german` property in `arrObj`. That means, if there is a `german` property in `arrObj` it should be "copied" out and it should be used as a key to produce the resultObj (3). If there is no `german` property then a key should be "Unknown" or whatever.

Note: There can be more entries in `resultObj` for e.g. `Montag`. Thats way `resultObj.Montag[i]` should be an array of objects.

**(1) Array of Objects**

```
const arrObj = [
{
    "day": {
    "string": "Monday",
    "Number": 1
    },
    "description": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "The first day of the week"
    },
    "german": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "Montag"
    }
},
{
    "day": {
    "string": "Tuesday",
    "Number": 2
    },
    "description": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "The second day of the week"
    }
},
{
    "day": {
    "string": "Wednesday",
    "Number": 3
    },
    "description": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "The third day of the week"
    },
    "german": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "Mittwoch"
    }
}
];
```

**(2) Array that should become the key for the new object**

```
const germanDays = ["Montag","Dienstag","Mittwoch","Donnerstag"];
```

**(3) Result should look like**

```
const resultObj =   {
"Montag": [
  {
    "day": {
      "string": "Monday",
      "Number": 1
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "The first day of the week"
    },
    "german": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "Montag"
    }
  }
],
"Dienstag": [
  {}
],
"Mittwoch": [
  {
    "day": {
      "string": "Wednesday",
      "Number": 3
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "The third day of the week"
    },
    "german": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "Mittwoch"
    }
  }
],
"Donnerstag": [
  {}
],
"Unknown": [
  {
    "day": {
      "string": "Tuesday",
      "Number": 2
    },
    "description": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "The second day of the week"
    }
  }
]
```

};

Comment: And you know that object properties do not have order in JavaScript? Just checking...

Comment: I know. I don’t care about ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> (possibly using map)

map, is meant for Array to Array mapping, a more appropriate function is reduce.

Here is an example.

```js
const germanDays = ["Montag","Dienstag","Mittwoch","Donnerstag"]

const arrObj = [
{
    "day": {
    "string": "Monday",
    "Number": 1
    },
    "description": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "The first day of the week"
    },
    "german": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "Montag"
    }
},
{
    "day": {
    "string": "Tuesday",
    "Number": 2
    },
    "description": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "The second day of the week"
    }
},
{
    "day": {
    "string": "Wednesday",
    "Number": 3
    },
    "description": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "The third day of the week"
    },
    "german": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "Mittwoch"
    }
},
{
    "day": {
    "string": "Monday",
    "Number": 1
    },
    "description": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "Just another text is here"
    },
    "german": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "Montag"
    }
}
];

const ret = germanDays.reduce((a, v) => {
  const f = arrObj.filter(f => f.german && f.german.value === v);
  a[v] = f;
  return a;
}, {
  "Unknown": arrObj.filter(f => !f.german)
});


console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Very nice. However, it is skipping the case if information is there, as in Tuesday, but no german property is there. Since it should be pushed in a new prop "unknown" ... as in the example `resultObj`

Comment: You could just do an `array.filter` for this, and add to your result.  Updated!!

Comment: Just figured out, that this approach fails, unfortunately, when there are more `german` props for an existing prop, e.g. `Monday`: https://jsbin.com/radowuqaca/edit?js,console

Comment: @Kalaschnik  Oh, yes.  Updated!!  Just needed filter again instead of find.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this (click the button "Run code snippet"):

```js
const arrObj = [
{
    "day": {
    "string": "Monday",
    "Number": 1
    },
    "description": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "The first day of the week"
    },
    "german": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "Montag"
    }
},
{
    "day": {
    "string": "Tuesday",
    "Number": 2
    },
    "description": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "The second day of the week"
    }
},
{
    "day": {
    "string": "Wednesday",
    "Number": 3
    },
    "description": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "The third day of the week"
    },
    "german": {
    "type": "string",
    "value": "Mittwoch"
    }
}
];


const germanDays = ["Montag", "Dienstag", "Mittwoch", "Donnerstag"];

const resultObj = {}

for (const item of arrObj) {
    if (item.german && item.german.value && germanDays.includes(item.german.value)) {
        addVal(item.german.value, item)
    } else {
        addVal('unknown', item)
    }
}

// helper func
function addVal(key, val) {
    if(!resultObj[key]) {
        resultObj[key] = []
    }
    resultObj[key].push(val)
}

console.log(resultObj)
```

Comment: Very nice. However, it is skipping the case if information is there, as in Tuesday, but no german property is there. Since it should be pushed in a new prop "unknown", as in the example `resultObj`

Comment: Although, Stackoverflow isn't for writing *the whole* code for you (but to give you a direction), fixed it and now it works according to your criteria.